# Bounty on a low-quality answer when there is an own high-quality answer

Tags: discussion, bounty

I asked a question for a problem which was (and is) very important for me. After 6 days of the 7 days period, I found a first solution and posted a very big and detailed answer for my own question. At the time when I was writing, another user posted a two-line question which is too much to be flagged as a "Not-an-answer" but which in fact is not helpful because he just recommends to post the question on another forum.

Because the answer is from the offerer of the bounty, I cannot assign any bounty to my own high-quality answer.

Now: It's not that I want my bounty back but somehow I feel that it's wrong to give the bounty to an answer which wasn't helpful in any way.

What would you do in such case? Give the bounty or flag the answer?

The question: [Problem setting up a user-space LXC container](https://askubuntu.com/questions/623789/problem-setting-up-a-user-space-lxc-container)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is great that you found your own answer and posted a good step-by-step guide.

You are under no obligation to award the bounty that was placed.  You can just let it lapse.

The auto-emails and prompts Stack Exchange makes are just for information - just to remind you that the bounty period is coming to an end and for you to make a decision if any of the answers actually helped you.

Thus - if the answer has not helped you, ignore it.

In this case, the OP was just commenting on your question - but they did not have sufficient rep to post a comment.  Flag the answer as "not an answer" and us moderators will take a look.  If they agree they would either just delete the answer outright or convert the answer into a comment.

I have decided to take the latter approach.

Comment: thanks. just one question: after the bounty period, if one answer remains: it doesn't automatically get the bounty?

Comment: An answer that has received up votes (but is not your answer) will receive half of the bounty if you yourself have not awarded it.